# Integer Solutions of $x^4+y^4=z^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Show that there do not exist any non-trivial integer solutions of $x^4+y^4=z^2$

This was asked in a number theory test, so I tried showing that there can't exist any Pythagorean Triple of the form $(x^2, y^2, z)$ and using possible congruence modulos with $3, 4, 5$ etc. but every time I get some case that remains to be disproved.
Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Other related links may be found courtesy of [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5E4%2By%5E4%3Dz%5E2%24&p=1).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks and sorry I didn't search thoroughly, maybe this can be closed

Comment: Well, take a look, if you feel satisfied with the dupe, you can click the "Yes, this answers my question" button. If not, you may find some better information in the last link.